# RequireJS config not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, requirejs

I am programming an MVC 5.1 application using BForms.

I have used exactly what in this page teachs: http://bforms.veritech.io/Start/Setup#example

After that, when I load the page, this error occurs: RequireJS config not found

This is part of the error (line number 72 is marked in red:

```
Línea 70:     @if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
Línea 71:     {
Línea 72:         @Html.RenderRequireJsSetup(Url.Content("~/Scripts"),
Línea 73:                                    Url.Content("~/Scripts/BForms/Components/RequireJS/require.js"),
Línea 74:                                    new[]
```

I have checked that all paths are correct, that is why I don't know where the error is.

This is the full layout page:

```
@using BForms.Html
@using RequireJS
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Gestión de Incidencias</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="initial-scale=1, 
        width=device-width, 
        maximum-scale=1, 
        user-scalable=no">

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    @*For IE7-8 support of HTML5 elements and responsive*@
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/BForms/Bundles/iefix.js")" 
    type="text/javascript">
    </script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="masthead">
            <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/desktop.png")" alt="Escritorio" title="Escritorio" /><br />
                    Escritorio
                </a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Incidencia")">
                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/events.png")" alt="Incidencias" title="Incidencias" /><br />
                    Incidencias
                </a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Agregar", "Incidencia")">
                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/add_event.png")" alt="Agregar Incidencia" title="Agregar Incidencia" /><br />
                    Agregar Incidencia
                </a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Backend")">
                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/backend.png")" alt="Escritorio" title="Escritorio" /><br />
                    Administración
                </a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Reporte")">
                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/reports.png")" alt="Escritorio" title="Escritorio" /><br />
                    Reportes
                </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - BTres Networks - Todos los derechos reservados</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/BFormsJS")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    @if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
    {
        @Html.RenderRequireJsSetup(Url.Content("~/Scripts"),
                                   Url.Content("~/Scripts/BForms/Components/RequireJS/require.js"),
                                   new[]
                                   {
                                        "~/Scripts/BForms/RequireJS.config"
                                   })
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.RenderRequireJsSetup(Url.Content("~/Scripts"),
                                   Url.Content("~/Scripts/BForms/Components/RequireJS/require.js"),
                                   new[]
                                   {
                                        "~/Scripts/BForms/RequireJS.Release.config"
                                   })
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Any help, please?
Thanks

EDIT:
I have used @Server.MapPath("~/Scripts/BForms/RequireJS.config") and it correctly shows the physical path to the file, so, the config file is actually in that location.

Comment: Finally, I have moved the config files to project root, and remove the third parameter of RenderRequireJsSetup, and it worked. Is this a RequireJS bug maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have moved the config files to project root, and remove the third parameter of RenderRequireJsSetup, and it worked. Is this a RequireJS bug maybe?